# How to access User Identity detail in mvc HtmlExtension method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

hellow guys thanks for your reply in advance.

I have to display many action links in many pages and I have authorization between user Roles so i am were coding if else in views but i wanna make it short thats why i go for htmlHelper extension method here is my code.

```
   public static MvcHtmlString ValidationActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, string AllowedRole)
{
     if (User.IsInRole(AllowedRole))// its given me error The User dosent exist in current context Am i missing some namespace or what ?
     {
                htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName);
     }                      
}
```

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke  both of your option is working thanks alot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access `User` within the extension method using

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, string AllowedRole)
{
    var user = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.User;
```

alternatively, you could pass `User` to the method by adding an additional parameter to your extension method.

Comment: how can i mark ur answer to correct my reputation is below 15

Comment: You just click the tick mark to the left of the answer

Comment: I have done many times but a message appear "Thanks for your feedback ! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score",,  just want to vote up your answer.

Comment: You cant vote yet (by clicking on the arrows), but you can accept by clicking the tick mark - [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)